# Not understanding Python String Strip() Method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this Python script and I'm not getting how .strip is able to remove "/n". From documentation you have to provide .strip() chracters to be removed from the string and it returns string w.o them. Is /n some kind of special case were .strip() ignores and it and returns a string w.o it?

```
from urllib import urlopen

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())

print "*" * 134
print urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines()

print "*" * 134
print WORDS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `.strip()` is not provided with any arguments, it strips all whitespace.  That includes newline, carriage return, tab, and space.  The newline character is `\n`, so it is included.  From the docs:

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. **If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.**

(Emphasis mine)